# Is Using Mainwindow in child windows in WPF causes mamory leaks?

Tags: c#, wpf, memory-leaks

I am developing a WPF application. In which I have total 5 wpf windows. I am using the variables (which are declared as public in mainwindow) in Child windows. So I am referencing Mainwindow in Child windows

For example in Child window I am using following code (Modified Constructor)

```
 public CaptureOptions(MainWindow parent)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        parentWindow = parent;

    }
```

I am doing like this in all 4 child windows.
Is this cause any memory leaks?

thanks,

Comment: maybe you should try to use the MVVM pattern instead of referencing the MainWindow in each ChildWindow.

Answer (score 0):

MainWindow is presumably your application window. It will stay alive for the length of the process so nothing can extend it's lifetime inappropriately via a stray reference. However, your main window references the child windows so these will be kept alive as the main window references them. This potentially means you are keeping objects alive longer than needed but it's not really a memory leak if you have 5 child windows and you keep the same five instances referenced.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a memory leak as long as you don't keep reference in MainWindow to any of children.

Your example is not a memory leak because child has reference to MainWindow which is opposite which means it's ok.